# E11000 duplicate key error index: id

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

i've created an api which works fine and i have added a user through an post requet however when i try to add another user with a different id i get this error:

```
SUCCESS: {
    code = 11000;
    errmsg = "E11000 duplicate key error index: matchmaking.users.$id_1 dup key: { : null }";
    index = 0;
    op =     {
        "__v" = 0;
        "_id" = 352523;
        birthday = "1998-10-09T23:00:00.000Z";
        country = denmark;
        name = Frederik;
    };
}
```

**UserSchema**

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
  _id: {
    type: SchemaTypes.Long,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  accessToken: String,
  email: String,
  name: String,
  birthday: Date,
  country: String,
  created_at: Date,
  updated_at: Date
});
```

Comment: How your id is generated... im assuming when you created second user _id were the same number. Can you show _id generation?

Comment: my ids are from a facebook user that i get from the graph api

Comment: Hm..in that case make sure that FB ids changes correctly before save. Index duplicate error can only show when you try to save new document with same index value. So this is where you need to look for problem.

Comment: well i tried to just hardcode an id which i'm sure is different. and it still give me this error?